# Nuxt3 - 404 Cannot find any route matching /api/submit

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am getting in Nuxt 3, i have a very simple example but it's not working:

from my vue component i am calling a api

```
<script setup>
async function submit(form) {
  this.loading = true;

  await $fetch('/api/submit', { method: 'POST', body: form })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Error!!!');
    });
</script>
```

File location:

```
-server
--api
---submit.post.ts
```

the api is simple as:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event);
  return Promise.resolve();
});
```

But in the client i get the 404 error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/submit 404 (Cannot find any route matching /api/submit.)
```

I think it just should get into the console log???

Comment: you named file submit.post but calls just submit. Rename file to submit,ts

Comment: No that is not the issue (I have tried it already), and beside that adding the HTTP method should work according to the Docs: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#matching-http-method

Comment: You are right. I would try simplest api response from example. No async and no empty returun values as you have.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Larra check my soloution

Answer (score 1):

@Lara
I could not get it to work with Promise but,

it works fine when you return a object like:

```js
 return {status: 'OK'}
```

I hope it will help you!